# Number items in GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to number the items added to a `GridView` automatically, preferably in a way that doesn't need any properties to be added to the objects in the `ItemsSource`.

My attempt has been using an `ItemContainerStyle`'s `Template` (simplified for your enjoyment), but I have not found anything I can bind to that will give me the index of the current item:

```
<Style x:Key="fooStyle"
       TargetType="GridViewItem">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock x:Name="numbering"
                     Text="{Binding to what exactly}" />
          <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" />
        </StackPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

How would you go about ensuring that the `numbering` `TextBlock` receives the number of the item in the list?

Note, this is for Windows Runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a temporary fix. It is not optimal, as it requires the items I add to the `GridView` to implement a special interface.

```
public interface INumberedItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int NumberInList { get; set; }
}

public class NumberedGridView : GridView
{
    protected override void OnItemsChanged(object e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);
        var i = 1;
        foreach (var item in Items.OfType<INumberedItem>())
        {
            item.NumberInList = i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can bind to `NumberInlist` in my XAML code.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure the "AlternationCount" property on the ItemsControl (in your case, GridView) is set to something (not NaN) and use the following binding:

```
<Binding Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}" Mode="OneWay"/>
```